# Getting error code of the first command in pipe in ash

Tags: pipe, error-handling, ash

I use `wget` to download a big file to two FIFOs like that:

```
wget <wget-args> -O - | tee -a "$fifo1" >> "$fifo2"
```

I want to retrieve the error code of `wget` on failure.

`set -o pipefail` returns error code of the rightmost command in a pipe so I can't be sure that the error code comes from `wget`.

So how can I do it in ash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redirect return code of wget to a file , here `$?` contains the return code

```
$ (wget <wget-args> -O - ; echo $? > result) | tee -a "$fifo1" >> "$fifo2"
```

Here the file result will contain the status code of your operation

```
$ cat result
  0
```

Comment: Why is the stdout from `wget` passed further to `tee` and call to `echo` is kind'a transparent?

Comment: I just replicated what you did, and tried giving you the return code of the first command

Comment: This won't work. The pipe is not getting any input, the `;` ends the first command.

Comment: That first part of the pipeline must run in a subshell so that the output of `wget` is piped to `tee`.  `( wget ...; echo ... >result ) | tee ...`

Comment: @Kusalananda please, post an answer and I'll accept it.