# Get return code of first piped command using eval?

Tags: bash, eval

I wish to execute different commands and check the return code afterwards before moving to the next steps in the script. At the same time I also wish to log the output of the executed commands to a file using the tee command.
Example:

```
#set non-existing folder
local_path="~/njn"
log_path_file="test.log"
cmd="ls -l ${local_path} | tee -a ${log_path_file}";
eval ${cmd}

returncode=$?
echo "execution result: ${returncode}"  | tee -a ${log_path_file};

if [ ${returncode} -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "success"  | tee -a ${log_path_file}
else
  echo "not success"  | tee -a ${log_path_file}
fi
```

returncode is 0 where it should be > 0

I want the returncode variable to have the actual return of the executed command (in this example, the ls -l command.

I've seen there's a solution using a file to write the output of the command to it and then reading the return code from it ([Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454875/getting-error-code-of-the-first-command-in-pipe-in-ash)), but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Related: [Getting error code of the first command in pipe in ash](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/454875)

Comment: This is the solution I've mentioned. Looking for a more elegant one

Comment: For `bash`, there is `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`. [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another). Not sure how it interacts with `eval` though.

Comment: Or [How do I capture the return status and use tee at the same time in korn shell?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/76162)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional testing, I've reached this code switch is wrapped nicely and returns the executed command return code.
The code which @Freddy have posted is nearly complete. The return code is exported inside the function but is not exported outside it.

The use of the shopt -s lastpipe was taken from this page: [Bash FAQ entry #24: "I set variables in a loop. Why do they suddenly disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Here is the final working solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

log_path_file="./logs/test.log"
exe_cmd()
{
    echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d---%r` [Info]: Command to execute: $@"  | tee -a ${log_path_file};
    echo ""  | tee -a ${log_path_file};
    echo ""  | tee -a ${log_path_file};

    set +m
    shopt -s lastpipe

    cmdResult=0
    {
            "$@"
            returncode=$?
            # save result code
            cmdResult=${returncode}

            if [ "$returncode" -eq 0 ]; then
              echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d---%r` [Info]: successfully executed \"$@\""
            else
              echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d---%r` [Info]: failed to execute \"$@\", exit code: ${returncode}"
            fi
    } 2>&1 | tee -a "$log_path_file"

    echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d---%r` [Info]: cmdResult result ${#cmdResult[@]}"

    return ${#cmdResult[@]};
}

cmd="scp some_user@$some_host:some_path/* a_local_path/sub_path";
exe_cmd ${cmd}
returncode=$?
echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d---%r` [Info]: scp execution result: ${returncode}"  | tee -a ${log_path_file};
```

Comment: You may want to run this through https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, it would be easier to just execute `ls -l` and act directly on its exit status:

```
if ls -l "$local_path"; then
    echo 'success'
else
    printf 'failure (code %d)\n' "$?"
fi | tee -a "$log_path_file"
```

In the `bash` shell, you may also investigate the values in the `PIPESTATUS` array:

```
$ false | true | true | false | false
$ printf '%s\n' "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1
0
0
1
1
```

In your case:

```
ls -l "$local_path" | tee -a "$log_path_file"

ls_status=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
if [ "$ls_status" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'success'
else
    printf 'failure (code %d)\n' "$ls_status"
fi | tee -a "$log_path_file"
```

Comment: @Kusalananda, I've tried running your code, all ok except that I didn't get the "No such file or directory" error in the logfile, only on the screen. Any idea why?

Comment: @T.M Because you never redirected the standard error stream. To do that, you would have to use `ls -l ... 2>&1`.  I did not include that, because that didn't seem like a requirement in the question.

Comment: I see, sorry if I wasn't clear about it. I've corrected my code and now I see that it does work perfectly! Marking this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function that takes the command as arguments and `tee`'s the output (stdout and stderr) to the logfile.

```
local_path="~/njn"
log_path_file="test.log"

function log_cmd ()
{
        {
                "$@"
                returncode=$?
                if [ "$returncode" -eq 0 ]; then
                  echo "[successfully executed \"$@\"]"
                else
                  echo "[failed to execute \"$@\", exit code: ${returncode}]"
                fi
                return $returncode

        } 2>&1 | tee -a "$log_path_file"
        # return exit code of first command in pipeline
        return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
}

log_cmd ls -l "$local_path"
log_cmd echo "hello world"
```

Comment: No thing is missing however. the function needs to return the exit code back so that it would be used the determine the next step.
Using 'return $?' before the function ends, brings us back to the original problem where it returns the exit code of the tee - 0.
If we remove the tee, it works, but not logging to the logfile :/

Comment: @T.M Added two return statements to return the exit code of the command before tee.